# Select rows from a DataFrame based on True or False in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Select rows from a DataFrame based on True or False in a column in pandas:

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'uid':["1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2"], 
        'type': ["a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a"], 
        'is_topup':["FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"],
       'label':["FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE","FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)  



   uid type  is_topup  label
0   1    a    FALSE  FALSE
1   1    a    FALSE  FALSE
2   1    b     TRUE   TRUE
3   1    a    FALSE  FALSE
4   2    a    FALSE  FALSE
5   2    b     TRUE   TRUE
6   2    b     TRUE   TRUE
7   3    a    FALSE  FALSE
8   3    b     TRUE   TRUE
9   3    b     TRUE   TRUE
10  3    a    FALSE  FALSE
```

---

I want to select a row in conditions like is

```
  uid type   is_topup  label
0   1    a    FALSE  FALSE
1   1    a    FALSE  FALSE
2   1    b     TRUE   TRUE
4   2    a    FALSE  FALSE
5   2    b     TRUE   TRUE
7   3    a    FALSE  FALSE
8   3    b     TRUE   TRUE
```

I tried to look at pandas documentation but did not find the answer.

Comment: what do you mean with "and stop in" ?

Comment: Can you explain which rows you want to drop. There doesn't seem to be a logical reason to drop them without you explaining which rows you want to drop. Why do I have to drop rows 3, 6, 9 and 10? Doesn't seem like droping duplicates (0 and 1 are duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the most efficient way but using `idxmax`:

```
new_df = df.groupby('uid').apply(lambda x: x[:(x['is_topup'] & x['label']).reset_index(drop=True).idxmax()+1])
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
       uid type  is_topup  label
uid                             
1   0    1    a     False  False
    1    1    a     False  False
    2    1    b      True   True
2   4    2    a     False  False
    5    2    b      True   True
3   7    3    a     False  False
    8    3    b      True   True
```

Comment: yes, but "unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'"

Comment: is `is_topup` and `label` `str`s? In such a case, replace `(x['is_topup'] & x['label'])` with `(x['is_topup'].eq('TRUE') & x['label'].eq('TRUE'))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that a simple

```
result = df.drop_duplicates()
```

should do the trick. At least your given example would work that way.

Comment: not like that, I want all uid and some row. example uid= 3 new, with 4 row and I want 2 row(7,8)  is_topup and label is change to TRUE TRUE